fast forward merge of outdated master
I have an outdated master branch which was updated back in 2020.
Now I want to sync my master branch with latest release branch, I tried below
git clone https://repo...
cd db-repo-1
git checkout release
git checkout master
git merge release

Here merge happens with fast-forward method and 1000+ files got changed/added.
Since here merged happened with fast-forward method, can I be sure that all the code present in the release branch is now in master too (master does not have anything extra and is exactly same as release) or there could be any scenarios where my master is still not in sync with release?
Note: I want all code from release to master as release has the latest code and trying to avoid re-write history option.

Fast forward means it was able to copy everything from the local release branch without needing to do any complicated merging (Though it's possible your local release branch is outdated). If git log shows you a commit, all its (transitive) parents should be present as well.

@dan1st I did fresh git clone and then checkout. So local branch are updated. Updated commands in original question

Another way to think about this is, if you merge release into master and it's a fast-forward merge, then it's the same result as deleting the master branch, and making a new branch called master starting from the release branch.

A fast-forward merge is simply a case where the head commit of the current branch is an ancestor of the head commit of the other branch. In this scenario, there is no need to create a merge commit between the two branches, because there aren't two different lines of development to combine, but just a single one, where one ref moved forward (the other branch), while the other one "stayed behind" (the current branch). Git resolves fast-forward merges by simply assigning to the ref of the current branch the commit pointed by the other branch (i.e. its head commit).

Often the current branch head is an ancestor of the named commit. [...] In this case, a new commit is not needed to store the combined history; instead, the HEAD (along with the index) is updated to point at the named commit, without creating an extra merge commit.

So, to answer your question, if a merge is resolved as a fast-forward merge, you can be sure that there is no data loss, as both branches are pointing to the exact same history of commits.

As a side note, a branch is just a ref, and it's implemented as a file containing the SHA1 of its head commit. It's really not that special. You can check that by simply opening with an editor any branch file contained in refs/heads, you will see the SHA1 of the branch's head commit. The whole heavy lifting is actually done via the commit DAG (the directed acyclic graph).

Thanks!! Can i also be sure that after this ff merge there is no additional code in master which is not present in release? Also all code from release is present in master ?

@AWS_Lernar Yes, you can be absolutely sure. Both branches are pointing to the same commit, and therefore to the same history of changes. Everything you've committed under release will be also under master after the ff merge.
